# How to merge multiple subjects into observable and emit on subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject, subject

I would like to merge multiple subjects (`fooSubject$`, `barSubject$`) into one observable (`filterChanged$`) and return the (initial) values (`_foo`, `_bar`), when I subscribe to merged observable (`filterChanged$`) and when one of the values change.

I already used `BehaviorSubject` (for both subjects) but then `filterChanged$` will emit twice on subscribe. How can I immediately return the values (`_foo`, `_bar`) when subscribe to observable `filterChanged$` without using `BehaviorSubject`?

```
export interface IFilterData {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilterService {
    public foo$: Observable<string>;
    public bar$: Observable<string>;
    public filterChanged$: Observable<IFilterData>;

    private fooSubject$: Subject<string>;
    private barSubject$: Subject<string>;
    private _foo: string;
    private _bar: string;

    constructor() {
        this._foo = 'InitialFoo';
        this._bar = 'InitialBar';

        this.foo$ = this.fooSubject$.asObservable();
        this.bar$ = this.barSubject$.asObservable();

        this.filterChanged$ = merge(this.fooSubject$, this.barSubject$).pipe(
            switchMap(() => {
                return of({
                    foo: this._foo,
                    bar: this._bar
                });
            })
        );
    }

    set foo(value: string) {
        this._foo = value;
        this.fooSubject$.next(value);
    }
    get foo(): string {
        return this._foo;
    }

    set bar(value: string) {
        this._bar = value;
        this.barSubject$.next(value);
    }
    get bar(): string {
        return this._bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might want to use `withLatestFrom`

Comment: `withLatestFrom` won't emit values on subscription. I am looking for a merged observable of BehaviorSubjects which will only emit once on subscription.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I already used BehaviorSubject (for both subjects) but then filterChanged$ will emit twice on subscribe.

This happens because, as you might now, when a `BehaviorSubject` is subscribed, it will emit its **latest values** synchronously to the **new subscriber**.

> How can I immediately return the values (_foo, _bar) when subscribe to observable filterChanged$

There is a way to achieve this, but note that, with this approach, the `BehaviorSubject`s won't store these `_foo` and `_bar` values.(there is a way to store them as well)

```js
combineLatest(
  this.fooSubject$.pipe(skip(1), startWith(this._foo)),
  this.barSubject$.pipe(skip(1), startWith(this._bar)),
),.subscribe(/* ... */)
```

this will wait until each observable emits once, then will emit when one of those 2 observables emit.

`skip(1)` is used because we don't want the values that are currently stored by the `Subjects`, but the `_foo` & `_bar` values.

Comment: I removed the private fields and use `BehaviorSubject`s now and store the value in the subject. When combining with the appropriate operator, I skip the first values of all `BehaviorSubject`s except of one. Thanks for the tip with the skip operator.